# Cforms II uploading error

Tags: wordpress

I have the cforms II plugin installed on my site. 
I have created a form but it doesn't seem to work as I can't upload any files.

When i'm trying to upload a file it only says:

```
"File upload failed. Please try again or contact the blog admin."
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could be the result of either:

1. Insufficient file permissions to the upload directory
2. Broken path to the file upload directory
3. Attempting to upload a file that's larger than the site's limit

Links of interest:

UPLOAD FILE FAILED AND FILE SIZE
http://www.deliciousdays.com/cforms-forum/troubleshooting/upload-file-failed-and-file-size/

http://www.wordimpressed.com/screencasts/screencast-increasing-the-wordpress-default-upload-size-limit/

How to Increase WordPress’ File Upload Size Correctly
http://www.wordimpressed.com/coding/how-to-increase-wordpress-file-upload-size-correctly/

I hope this helps!